# How to find constant for feynman's technique of integration $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\ln\left(x^{2}+1\right)}{x^{2}+1}dx$

Tags: definite-integrals

I've got an integral
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\ln\left(x^{2}+1\right)}{x^{2}+1}dx$$
and when I used Feynman's technique of integration
$$I(t) = \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\ln\left(x^{2}+t\right)}{x^{2}+1}dx$$
I got the result
$$\pi\cdot\ln\left(\sqrt{t}+1\right)$$
but the problem is that after integrating $I(t)$, I must include constant $C$ so the final result should be
$$I(t)=\pi\cdot\ln\left(\sqrt{t}+1\right) + C$$
and I have no idea how to calculate that $C=0$

Comment: This is a duplicate, try to avoid answering duplicates. I’ll find a link shortly

Comment: [duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/359031/815585) - one of many

Comment: You can also [see this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4384632/how-do-we-find-the-exact-value-of-int-0-infty-frac-ln-n-left1x2) for a generalisation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$I(0) = 2\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\ln\left(x\right)}{x^{2}+1}dx$$

Let $t=1/x$

$$I(0) = -2\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\ln\left(t\right)}{t^{2}+1}dt$$

Add them

$$I(0)=0~~\Longrightarrow ~~C=0$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply

Comment: You are welcome. If it solves your question, please $\checkmark$ my answer :) @Bruh

Comment: I will, just have to wait 6 minutes

Comment: This is a duplicate (more than one time I’m pretty sure)